# excel vba call subroutine with variables

Tags: excel, vba, subroutine

I defined the following subroutine:

```
Sub EnterCellValueMonthNumber(cells As range, number As Integer)

range(cells).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = number

End Sub
```

When I call the subroutine like this:

```
EnterCellValueMonthNumber ("N23:Q23",1)
```

I get the following error message:

```
Compile error Expected: =
```

I have no idea why I get this message. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You would call the sub as

```
EnterCellValueMonthNumber "N23:Q23", 1
```

No brackets. Or

```
Call EnterCellValueMonthNumber("N23:Q23", 1)
```

Brackets, and `Call` before it.

Also, your Sub is expecting a Range object as the first argument and you're supplying a string; you should change the signature of the sub to:

```
Sub EnterCellValueMonthNumber(cells As String, number As Integer)
```

Also, I'm uncertain as to what you are trying to achieve with this code as it will only set the top-left cell of the range to 1. Would something like

```
Range(cells).Value = number
' Or, if you're going to be passing in something more complex later...
Range(cells).FormulaR1C1 = number
```

be more appropriate?

I'd also be very wary of using `Range("...")` without specifying which sheet you are referring to. This will act on whichever is the active sheet and can thus cause unexpected problems, almost always prefer `SheetX.Range("...")`. Similarly for using `.Select`, it's unnecessary, and can only cause problems for you in the future.

Comment: Although I defined another subroutine:                           Sub EnterCellValue(cells As range)

    range(cells).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "M"
    
End Sub                                                                 and called it like this: EnterCellValue ("N23:Q23") and had no problems. This is irritating.

Answer (score 4):

You actually have 2 issues.

First the actual answer to your question. You need to say:

```
Call EnterCellValueMonthNumber("N23:Q23",1)
```

But that still wont work if you run it, since you have set `cells` of type `range`... set it as type `string` using this instead:

```
Sub EnterCellValueMonthNumber(cells As String, number As Integer)
    Range(cells).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
Sub EnterCellValueMonthNumber(ByVal cells As String, number As Integer)

    Range(cells).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = number

End Sub
```